# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 - Mouse freezes

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mouse

I updated my windows 7 ultimate 64 with some microsoft recommendations (security and others), after this when I run Visual Studio 2013 my mouse freezes and only returns after logoff.
I applied visual studio update RC5 again, without results.
I removed windows service pack 1, without results.

Please, I appreciate some sugestions.

Thanks, best

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the ".v12.suo" file and try to open the solution again.

if that not working for you, have a look here:
[Visual Studio 2013 hangs when opening a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120705/visual-studio-2013-hangs-when-opening-a-solution)

Comment: Hi DeJa Vu, Thanks for reply.
Indeed VS2013 does not hangs, only the mouse hangs.
If I use keyboard, it´s possible load a project/solution.
This is very strange.
I don´t know what to do.
Please, ideas?

Comment: Actually its DeJaVo not DeJaVu (indeed there is a typo but it is deliberately). anyhow, I think you can try the suggestion here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617670/why-vs-2013-is-very-slow