# Why does Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 restart unpredictably when it loads very large C++ and C# solutions?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013

Yesterday, I encountered the problem multiple times that Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 restart unpredictably when it loads very large C++ and C# solutions.

I researched Stack Overflow and found this particular article: [Visual Studio 2013 hangs when opening a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120705/visual-studio-2013-hangs-when-opening-a-solution)
which suggests deleting the suo files. However, when I  tried that the problem persisted.

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and still the problem persisted.

I then tried loading a smaller solution consisting of a C# solution and a C++ project and that succeeded in loading, compiling and linking.

I was wondering why I suddenly encountered this problem. Could the cause of the problem be related to the amount of 64 bit physical memory I have installed on my 64-bit desktop system? Alternatively, could it be due to a computer virus even though my desktop system has an antivirus package installed. We are tring to avoid reimaging the disk of my 64-bit desktop system and reinstalling all the software which could take 2 days to complete. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The same or similar problem for me, but Visual Studio restarts after clicking "Close" on its windows (instead of just closing). The VS solution is not too big.

Comment: If you have installed code analytic tools such as re sharper then you may need to look at that direction. For instance, re-sharper has solution wide inspection of code which is likely to slowdown. http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206104498-Visual-Studio-with-ReSharper-is-slow

Comment: @Serge Rogatch, Does my Visual Studio 2013 problem have anything to do with my 55% RAM memory utilization as reported by Task Manager--Performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open file explore and past this command
  '%AppData%..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache'
- Then remove 'ComponentModelCache' folder.
- Restart the visual studio.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably some plug-in misbehaving. You can try disabling them (`Tools => Extensions and Updates`) and experimentally determine which one is causing the issue.

If you want to go all-in, you can debug it:

- Download and install [WinDbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx) 32-bit
- Run Visual Studio under windbg: `windbg -g "%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\ide\devenv.exe" c:\my\solution.sln`

  - Watch the incredible amount of debug info VS spews into
    WinDbg
- If Windbg breaks, inspect the stack - maybe some DLLs on it will clue you into which plug-in is the culprit.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am about to vote positive for your answer.

Comment: My manager is wondering why  my MIcrosoft Visual Studio 2013 problem only occurs on my Lenovo 64 bit desktop workstation and does not occur on the desktop workstation of the other developers who have the same software tools installed as me. Any help is greatly appreciated. hank you very much.