# Visual Studio 2013 hangs after opening a solution that was opened with VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

We have a solution that was originally developed in Visual Studio 2013. One of my colleagues opened the solution and worked on it on Visual Studio 2015 and pushed changes to GIT.

Now when we try to open the solution back in Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio hangs while loading the project and we need to kill the process.

We found that if we delete the file `Configuration.v12.suo` in the `.sln` directory Visual Studio 2013 opens the solution and we are able to work on it normally. But `Configuration.v12.suo` is recreated. So next time we will encounter the same problem until we again delete this file.

We are looking for a more elegant way to solve this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Were the solution/projects converted to VS2015?  It doesn't appear like it.

Comment: @rrirower no, it was not. Otherwise we would not have been able to load it in vs2013 at all in my opinion.

Comment: Have you checked to see if it's hanging because VS is trying to validate your Microsoft username?

Comment: @rrirower don't think it's the case. This doesn't happen on any other solution I open. If I delete the `Configuration.v12.suo` it immediately works. And even if I wait for a long period of time it still hangs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 hangs when opening a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120705/visual-studio-2013-hangs-when-opening-a-solution)

Comment: @rrirower Tried what's mentioned in that post. Doesn't work except deleting `Configuration.v12.suo` which as I mentioned above just being recreated for some strange reason - We are looking for a more permanent solution.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but did you have any luck with this? We don't use GIT, but other than that I have this exact problem and am clueless

Comment: Why would you push a suo file to GIT? Suo files are "solution user options", and are likely to be different every time, for every user. It probably contains information VS2013 can't read properly because it has user information from VS2015